# Looking for a specific quote about keys and transparent encryption implementation

Tags: encryption, obscurity

I'm struggling to find a quote advising that we should be comfortable in sharing details of encryption methods and implementation with would-be attackers and the system still remain secure. The idea is that the keys are what we should be protecting as opposed to some obscurity in our code and approach.

Does anybody have the quote I'm talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

From the wikipedia page:

> Kerckhoffs's principle (also called Kerckhoffs's desideratum,
>   assumption, axiom, doctrine or law) of cryptography was stated by
>   Netherlands born cryptographer Auguste Kerckhoffs in the 19th century:
>   A cryptosystem should be secure even if everything about the system,
>   except the key, is public knowledge.